# Users get UAC when installing shared print drivers through web interface

Tags: windows-7, network-printer, print-server, uac

I'm having a problem where users on Windows 7 (Only OS tried though) are getting the UAC prompt when attempting to install printer drivers from a Windows print server. However, they are only receiving the UAC prompt when trying to install the driver through the IIS site. They can install printer drivers without the UAC prompt when installing through the print server share at \\printserver.

I have researched, but all I have come up with is group policy settings which may cause the user to receive the UAC prompt (specifically, the Point and Print settings and have adjusted them in many ways to no avail).

Has anyone else run into this problem or any suggestions of things I can try? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you change a user GPO or a computer GPO? Have you waiting for Group Policy to update? Have you restarted a computer?

Comment: Yeah, what user5870571 said.  Make sure you run a `gpupdate /force` before testing any group policy changes.  I'm pretty sure you're on the right track with your point and print restrictions, too;  I had to set that to allow from forest when I had a similar issue.

Comment: I changed it in both user and computer gpo and added to allow them to install the drivers.  It does work if you install from the share but no on the website.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft:

*You can use the Point and Print Restrictions Group Policy setting to control how users can install printer drivers **from print servers**.*

That of course has no bearing on users installing printer drivers from the printers builtin web page, which explains the UAC prompt when users attempt to do so.

Comment: Yes I have it working from the network share but not from the website.  I don't want to turn off UAC on the workstations.  I just want to allow them to use the website to install the printer drivers.